# How can I make AC powered 5mm LED string? (with more than 16 LEDs)

Tags: led, power, ac, mains

I want to make an AC powered 5mm LED string. I searched a lot but I never found a working one.

I just tried [one experiment](http://m.instructables.com/id/Glow-leds-using-AC-current220-250V/step2/Adding-diodes/) from the Instructables site.

But when I connected it to AC power, one resister got blown. Anyone please tell me how can I do this easily?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't do your math.

Comment: Which resistor and precisely what part number did you fit?

Comment: Please don't vote to close this question. A good answer should provide a warning to inexperienced people who want to play with mains electricity.

Comment: Those are the components which I added to the bcb bord...

Comment: Those are the components which I added to the bcb bord. 1N4007 diode ,1mega ohm 1/4 walt resister,220 ohm 1 walt resister, capacitor 0.47 mf 450v, capacitor 100 mf 50v

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/kqde5ln59/  here is the image of blown resister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All parts of this circuit should be regarded as being at mains voltage at all times. It can kill anyone who touches it.**

Note that in the comments someone says

- Capacitor in parallel to R1= 0.47 Microfarad 450V

Note that it should be a 450V cap for 230 VAC mains.
And it should be an X rated cap (across mains use).
The capacitance will affect the current provided.

Current will VERY APPROXIMATELY be V x 2 x Pi x C
At 110VAC, 60 Hz
Ima ~~~= 40 x CuF
So for 1 uF I ~= 40 mA.
I have ignored R2 as impedance of the capacitor dominates.

Diode polarity matters.

Comment: Sir ,thank you for your answer....so what change should I want to make in my circut

Comment: Those are the two images of circut which i created..
http://postimg.org/image/kqde5ln59/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/61fbtp2a7/